# How to monitor all threads of the same process id across CPU cores?

Tags: linux, multithreading, command-line

I'd like to watch closer how the threads of a process is spread across all CPU cores and how much of each core each thread is consuming.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:
`top -Hp <process pid>`